# GCE BOOTING not running

Tags: google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I cant remote and ping my Compute Engine after modifing in attaching a disk to a running instance(add storage on my default 10gig virtual machine)
i think i change the boot-disk priority or disk booting...
any idea how can i  fixed it. our system down T_T

**heres my ouput from developer console**

```
Scan for option roms

Searching bootorder for: HALT

drive 0x000fd830: PCHS=0/0/0 translation=lba LCHS=1024/255/63 s=20971520

Space available for UMB: 000c0000-000eb800

Returned 118784 bytes of ZoneHigh

e820 map has 7 items:

  0: 0000000000000000 - 000000000009fc00 = 1 RAM

  1: 000000000009fc00 - 00000000000a0000 = 2 RESERVED

  2: 00000000000f0000 - 0000000000100000 = 2 RESERVED

  3: 0000000000100000 - 00000000bfffd000 = 1 RAM

  4: 00000000bfffd000 - 00000000c0000000 = 2 RESERVED

  5: 00000000fffbc000 - 0000000100000000 = 2 RESERVED

  6: 0000000100000000 - 0000000400000000 = 1 RAM

Unable to lock ram - bridge not found

Changing serial settings was 3/2 now 3/0

enter handle_19:

  NULL

Booting from Hard Disk...

Booting from 0000:7c00

Changing serial settings was 0/0 now 3/0

Start bios (version 1.7.2-20140408_181335-google)

No Xen hypervisor found.

Unable to unlock ram - bridge not found

Ram Size=0xc0000000 (0x0000000300000000 high)

Relocating low data from 0x000e0fe0 to 0x000ef780 (size 2161)

Relocating init from 0x000e1851 to 0xbffd07b0 (size 63267)

CPU Mhz=2500

=== PCI bus & bridge init ===

PCI: pci_bios_init_bus_rec bus = 0x0

=== PCI device probing ===

Found 4 PCI devices (max PCI bus is 00)

=== PCI new allocation pass #1 ===

PCI: check devices

=== PCI new allocation pass #2 ===

PCI: map device bdf=00:03.0  bar 0, addr 0000c000, size 00000040 [io]

PCI: map device bdf=00:04.0  bar 0, addr 0000c040, size 00000040 [io]

PCI: map device bdf=00:03.0  bar 1, addr febfe000, size 00001000 [mem]

PCI: map device bdf=00:04.0  bar 1, addr febff000, size 00001000 [mem]

PCI: init bdf=00:01.0 id=8086:7110

PIIX3/PIIX4 init: elcr=00 0c

PCI: init bdf=00:01.3 id=8086:7113

Using pmtimer, ioport 0xb008, freq 3579 kHz

PCI: init bdf=00:03.0 id=1af4:1004

PCI: init bdf=00:04.0 id=1af4:1000

Found 4 cpu(s) max supported 4 cpu(s)

MP table addr=0x000fdab0 MPC table addr=0x000fdac0 size=300

SMBIOS ptr=0x000fda90 table=0x000fd8a0 size=490

Memory hotplug not enabled. [MHPE=0xffffffff]

ACPI DSDT=0xbfffe020

ACPI tables: RSDP=0x000fd870 RSDT=0xbfffdff0

Scan for VGA option rom

Machine UUID a58f5636-0ae6-77c6-d815-b32671ad3613

WARNING - Timeout at i8042_flush:68!

All threads complete.

Found 0 lpt ports

Found 0 serial ports

found virtio-scsi at 0:3

Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@0,0

Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@1,0

virtio-scsi vendor='Google' product='PersistentDisk' rev='1' type=0 removable=0

virtio-scsi blksize=512 sectors=20971520


Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@254,0

Searching bootorder for: /pci@i0cf8/*@3/*@0/*@255,0

Scan for option roms

Searching bootorder for: HALT

drive 0x000fd830: PCHS=0/0/0 translation=lba LCHS=1024/255/63 s=20971520

Space available for UMB: 000c0000-000eb800

Returned 118784 bytes of ZoneHigh

e820 map has 7 items:

  0: 0000000000000000 - 000000000009fc00 = 1 RAM

  1: 000000000009fc00 - 00000000000a0000 = 2 RESERVED

  2: 00000000000f0000 - 0000000000100000 = 2 RESERVED

  3: 0000000000100000 - 00000000bfffd000 = 1 RAM

  4: 00000000bfffd000 - 00000000c0000000 = 2 RESERVED

  5: 00000000fffbc000 - 0000000100000000 = 2 RESERVED

  6: 0000000100000000 - 0000000400000000 = 1 RAM

Unable to lock ram - bridge not found

Changing serial settings was 3/2 now 3/0

enter handle_19:

  NULL

Booting from Hard Disk...

Booting from 0000:7c00
```

Comment: @jk i know but the google cloud redirect me here for support

Comment: Can you post what specific commands you ran after attaching the instance? Presumably you used fdisk; do you know what you changed?

Comment: Hi, I suggested an edit with more polished question and more troubleshooting info we need from you. Riccardo

Answer (score 1):

You can attach the affected disk to a new or existing instance [see link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks#attachdiskrunninginstance), and modify the changes. For more information about restoring a snapshot to a larger disk follow [this link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks#restoresnapshotlargersize), and for more information about re-partitioning a root persistent disk follow [this article](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks#repartitionrootpd)